# How to know what object type does QTabWidget tab hold?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qtabwidget

Lets say there are 3 classes `Foo1`, `Foo2` and `Foo3`. They are inherit `QWidget`. I now place each of them info a `QTabWidget` object.

```
QWidget* foo1 = new Foo1();
ui->tbMain->addTab(foo1, "Untitled*");

QWidget* foo2 = new Foo2();
ui->tbMain->addTab(foo2, "Untitled*");

QWidget* foo3 = new Foo3();
ui->tbMain->addTab(foo3, "Untitled*");
```

Now I select different tabs and a signal is emited and this slot catches it:

```
void MainWindow::on_tbMain_currentChanged(int index)
{
     QWidget* widget = ui->tbMain->widget(index);
}
```

I can retrieve the object that is in the currently selected tab. But i can retrieve it as `QWidget`, and I need to know either it is type `Foo1`, `Foo2` or `Foo3`? How can I do that? I would apreciate all help!

Comment: use [qobject_cast](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) to cast to Foo1, Foo2, Foo3

Comment: But I dont know which object to expect, Foo1 2 or 3.

Comment: What if you add objeectName to identify every type and check it in slot? Like `foo1->setObjectName("Foo1");`

Comment: How would I check it then?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the original class name with `->metaObject()->className()`

Example:

```
QWidget* foo1 = new Foo1();
qDebug() << foo1->metaObject()->className();

// will print "Foo1"

if(QString(foo1->metaObject()->className()) == "Foo1") {
    Foo1* f1 = qobject_cast<Foo1*>(foo1)
}
```

Or use `qobject_cast<>` and check return value.

```
QWidget* foo2 = new Foo2();
Foo1* f2 = qobject_cast<Foo1*>(foo2);

// f2 == NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
void MainWindow::on_tbMain_currentChanged( int index )
{
    QWidget* widget = ui->tbMain->widget( index );

    if ( auto foo1 = dynamic_cast< Foo1* >( widget ) )
    {
        // If the cast is successful it is a Foo1 object. And you call it's functions.
        // ...
    }
    else if ( auto foo2 = dynamic_cast< Foo2* >( widget ) )
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if ( auto foo3 = dynamic_cast< Foo3* >( widget ) )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But if there is a common property for those `Foo*` classes which you want to use, than it would be more elegant if you create a `FooBase` class and than derive the `Foo1` ... classes from that. In this case you only need to cast once.

```
class FooBase : public QWidget
{
public:
    virtual void set( /**/ ) = 0;
};

class Foo1 : public FooBase
{
public:
    virtual void set( /**/ ) { qDebug() << "Foo1::set()"; }
};
```

Then you could write this:

```
void MainWindow::on_tbMain_currentChanged( int index )
{
    auto foo = dynamic_cast< FooBase* >( ui->tbMain->widget( index ) );
    if ( foo )
    {
        foo->set( /**/ );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I actually have it done like you presented. I have a base class that derives qwidget and further classes that derive from base class. I will try this second way, thank you. Is there a clean way of checking which foo subclass are you if for example one of that classes had some extra method and I needed it? Is it your first code example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setObjectName` to identify the objects in QT.
It can be used as below :

```
QWidget* foo1 = new Foo1();
foo1->setObjectName("Foo1");
```

To get back the Identity of object you can use

```
QString myObjName = foo1->objectName()
```